# how can I eliminate infopath formular

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a list sharepoint and I edit it with infopath.
Now I want to have my old list before infopath .
I tried to delete the from from the server but it dosent work.
any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for both SharePoint 2010 and 2013. Go to the list where you wanna get rid of the custom InfoPath forms, go to list/library settings > Form Settings > Select "Use the default SharePoint form" and if you like to get rid of the customized forms, check the box for deleting the forms from the server.

[image]

Or you could also use SharePoint Designer and navigate to the current site, and select the list and look after the box called "Forms". Here will all the current forms for the list be displayed. The standard form names are:

- DispForm.aspx
- EditForm.aspx
- NewForm.aspx

If your old list forms remain, just set the above ones to default. If they are modified, use the first option to restore the old forms. In the picture i got some custom InfoPath forms, but the default are set as the list default.

[image]

Comment: How can I change the formular of infopath to be just like my new Editform with new items.Because every time I open infopath I see only the default EditForm and not the newer .Thank you

Comment: Just select the "editifs.aspx" and set it as default from SharePoint Designer. This action sets your custom editform to default.

Comment: I create a new formular and set it as default,but it steel have the old formular.